# Can't read CSV file using data Loader 59

Tags: csv

I tried all three suggestions from another question asked in this community
"`Data loader CSV Error: Can't read from CSV file`"
and none of those answers solved my problem.

- I just loaded Data Loader v59.00 yesterday. Is there something specific about this new version that is causing a problem?
- When I looked back at the the version (v57.0.1) I had on my old computer, there was no line for anything about the process.mappingFile=. Is it possible that it is not needed and that is just "confusing" DataLoader?

Comment: We are having this issue in our company as well. Has anyone know what is causing this issue please? Thanks, Joana

Comment: For anyone running into the issue, I recommend downloading v58 [here](https://github.com/forcedotcom/dataloader/releases/tag/v58.0.4). This is most likely a bug that needs to be fixed by Salesforce, so the prior version should suffice until it's fixed. The exact same file worked fine for me on v58.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this problem by:

In the Dataloader 59.0 Settings:

in the "Other Delimiters:" box, remove the "-"

Click OK.

Comment: Downloaded DL v59.0.0 and hit this exact error. CodeBabe solution worked.

Answer (score 0):

v59 is very picky regarding the CSV format. My Excel exports CSV's WITHOUT quotes and DL v59 wants CSV WITH quotes. I just used "Ron's CSV Editor" to "fix" a CSV file that was constantly giving the error and it went right thru this time.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into an issue with a file as well and reached out to support.  They referred me to this help article [Error 'CSV Error: Invalid CSV file format' with unicode CSV files](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000383918&language=en_US&type=1), but that didn't fix the issue.  I ended up using an older version of Dataloader and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same problem. I deleted the process.mappingFile line from the config file and it worked. I suggest cutting the line out and paste it elsewhere just in case.

I am currently using v58.0.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded version 60 and this solved the issue. PIA!